# I need rainfall_parameters to be 7 statements, how can I alter the specific function from the 8 it currently has and still have the program work?

Tags: python, function, pylint

```
"""A program to read a CSV file of rainfalls and print the totals
   for each month.
"""

from os.path import isfile as is_valid_file

def filename():
    """get's the filename"""
    infile = input('Input csv file name? ')
    while not is_valid_file(infile):
        print('File does not exist.')
        infile = input('Input csv file name? ')
    return infile

def read_file(file):
    """reads the file"""
    datafile = open(file) 
    data = datafile.read().splitlines()
    datafile.close()
    return data

def rainfall_parameters(data):
    """organises data into month and num_days and returns a list of 
    (month, rainfall) tuples"""
    results = []
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        month = int(columns[0])
        num_days = int(columns[1])        
        total = total_rainfall(columns, num_days)
        results.append((month, total))
    return results

def total_rainfall(columns, num_days):
    """gets the total rainfall"""
    total = 0
    for col in columns[2:2 + num_days]:
        total += float(col)
    return total

def print_results(results):
    """prints the monthly total rainfalls"""
    print('Monthly total rainfalls')
    for (month, total_rain) in results:
        print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, total_rain))    

def main():
    """Prompt the user to provide a csv file of rainfall data, process the 
       given file's data, and print the monthly rainfall totals. 
       The file is assumed to have the month number in column 1, the number 
       of days in the month in column 2, and the floating point rainfalls 
       (in mm) for that month in the remaining columns of the row.
    """
    global_file = filename()
    global_cols = read_file(global_file)
    global_results = rainfall_parameters(global_cols)
    print_results(global_results)
   
main()
```

Comment: 7 statements or 7 columns ?

Comment: 7 statements. Every function currently fits that criteria bar rainfall_parameters(), which has 8 statements from "results = []" through to "return results". The function gives the correct output as it is currently written, this is simply a pylint requirement for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd requirement, but you can remove a couple local variables:

```
def rainfall_parameters(data):
    """organises data into month and num_days and returns a list of 
    (month, rainfall) tuples"""
    results = []
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        #month = int(columns[0])  # no longer needed
        #num_days = int(columns[1])  # no longer needed
        total = total_rainfall(columns, int(columns[1]))  # move num_days
        results.append((int(columns[0]), total))  # move month
    return results
```

Comment: Yes it's not a normal requirement, it's part of teaching us functional decomposition of a messy program. That did the trick though, thank you!